# Track 3D "plane" (small depth) through a 3D matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, 3d, tracking

I'm writing a segmentation algorithm for segmenting pieces of paper in a book. However, the pieces of paper are crumpled so segmentation is nonlinear. Imagine taking a piece of paper, crumpling it into a ball, straightening it back out, and doing that for all pages in a book.

I have attached a 2D slice from the 3D matrix of binary values (0 for not on page, and 1 for on a page). Note that some of the pages are torn down the middle. I have constructed a full 3D matrix of the entire volume.

[image]

What kind of algorithm can I run that will track a single page at a time that runs through the 3D volume?

The above slice is from a algorithm that generates a binary matrix. I have included the original slice below that has a grey scale to it.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you have a 3D binary image which is a tomography of a book ? This picture you show us doesn't tell if you are scanning across a single page or several of them.

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah: can you elaborate ? I don't see the connection between the problem at hand and edge detection.

Comment: @YvesDaoust this is a scan perpendicular to the front of the book. In other words, this view is looking longways down the book

Comment: @YvesDaoust So, essentially I need an algorithm that tracks each page as the "view" moves through the book (again, moving through the book longways)

Comment: Is the 3D image binary ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's a tif file. I have implemented a threshold algorithm that generates images like the one above. I have added an original image as well. The threshold algorithm convert the image in to a simple binary matrix. I have then implemented a script that takes in all the binary matrices (from csv files) and constructs one big 3D matrix covering the entire volume

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113813/discussion-between-kendall-weihe-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah that doesn't outline a tracking algorithm. The idea here is I track the 3D page surface, and then run an algorithm to extract a 2D plane in the center of the page

Comment: @KendallWeihe sorry yeah i realized too; I've got a rough idea here if you wanna have a look

Comment: Could you solve this yourself by hand ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust kinda defeats the point of asking on SO

Comment: This really is an interesting problem. It's a 3d-ification of edge detection in a 2d gradient followed by e.g. thinning and pixel chaining to obtain vectors. Presumably you want surface detection in the 3d gradient (adaptation of  Canny?) followed by thinning in 3d and connecting 3d voxels in a 2d surface lattice.

Comment: @Gene spot on! There has to be a way to track the 3D edges using an eigenvector, right?

Comment: @Gene like maybe compute the normal in all 6 3D directions where 2 of the 6 should be perpendicular to the layer surfaces. But the problem remains, how do we "track" because if two layers touch at one point, the point could cross layers. Although, a workaround might be to have some sort of memory of previous and future points and implement a constraint from layers crossing.

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah: you miss the point. If a task cannot be performed by hand, no vision algorithm will do better.

Comment: @KendallWeihe The "touching" problem is very common in vision algorithms... E.g. trying to detect the edge of the road where a tree's shadow crosses it.  Problem-specific context is the only way out. Here you'd need something like accumulating all the "patches" where there's no touching ambiguity, then try to connect these into distinct, non-strictly intersecting surfaces that "look like pages" according to what you know about the real pages. There are probably other approaches. (I don't see eigenvectors as very helpful.)